# Can't move executables

Tags: bash

I'm working on this script but the option `-x` isn't working, it's supposed to move only the executable files.

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
$ sh wizlast.sh u555 -x
mv: target ‘./u555/ud’ is not a directory
```

it targets the right file (*ud*) but doesn't move it. I tried different types of combinations.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 dir=$1


if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
    echo "ERROR: no argument"
    exit 1  # pas 0
else
    case $2 in                                                                                                                                                                                               
    -d) 
     mv $dir/* /tmp/*
     echo 'moving with -d'        
     ;;
    -x)
     find -executable -type f | xargs mv -t "$dir"/* /tmp
     echo 'moving executables'
     ;;
     *)
     mv $dir/* /tmp/
     echo 'no flag passed so moving all'
     echo "mv $dir/* /tmp/"
     ;;
esac
fi
```

Comment: you dont need to use `-t` at all.

Comment: you're using POSIX syntax despite using a _bash_ shebang. Bash syntax allow `if (( $# < 1 )); then …`

Comment: ... and ... running it as `sh wizlast.sh ....` (the `sh` part) doesn't  help. If you're running it as `wizlast.sh ...` and getting `command not found` (or similar), just run it as `./wizlast.sh ....`. Running with `sh` leaves you open to problems on a system where `/bin/sh` is really the bourne shell (and not a renamed bash). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're working with `Bash` you should leverage it's tools and syntax improvement.

### Solution `for` loop and *globbing*

So instead of using `find` you can use [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/globbing) and `[[ -x ]]` to test if the current file is executable:

```bash
for f in "$dir"/*; do
  if [[ -x $f ]]; then
    mv "$f" /tmp
  fi
done
```

It use the *conditionnal expression* `-x` in `[[ … ]]`:

> **-x file**
>        True if file exists and is executable

#### As a one-liner

You can rewrite it like: `for f in "$dir"/*; do [[ -x $f ]] && mv "$f" /tmp; done`

#### Deeper search (d>1)

Current loop is limited to what is directly in your "$dir/", if you want to explore deeper like "$dir/*/*/*" you will need:

1. to toggle the [`globstar` shell option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar) using [`shopt` built-in](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/shopt) ;
2. update your glob in the `for` loop to use it: `"$dir"/**`

```bash
shopt -s globstar # enable/set
for f in "$dir"/**/*; do [[ -x $f ]] && mv "$f" /tmp; done
shopt -u globstar # disable/unset
```

#### Arithmethic context

Bash has syntactic sugar, that let you replace:

```bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then … fi
```

with

```bash
if (( $# < 1 )); then … fi
```

More about *Arithmetic Expression* read articles at:
1. [wooledge's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) ;
2. [bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr).

Comment: When i execute the one-liner it gives me this

wizlast2.sh: 16: wizlast2.sh: [[: not found
wizlast2.sh: 16: wizlast2.sh: [[: not found

Comment: Okay it works, thanks  , one ran it as ./file.sh and not sh file.sh it worked

Comment: @user3742475 running it as `sh file` use the `/bin/sh` that might be a different interpreter than Bash. The shebang at the beginning tell the script which interpreter to use so no need to repeat it in the console. Hence `./file.sh` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

`man mv` shows:

```
-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
```

You can't use `$dir/*` as a target directory, as the shell expands it and treats the first file in the list as the target (hence the error).

Comment: The error OP has gotten is due to xargs being used incorrectly, although this will also cause it not to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this format

For example to move files into `$dir`

```
find -executable -type f | xargs -I{} mv {} "$dir"/
```

The `I{}` tell xargs to replace and occurence of `{}` with the strings from pipe, so after `mv` each string is substituted before the directory `"$dir"/` and the command works like normal.

The reason yours wasn't working was the strings from the find were read last and so treated as the directory to move into.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use wildcards in the destination part of a `mv` command, so instead of

```
mv $dir/* /tmp/*
```

do

```
mv $dir/* /tmp/
```

Comment: When i change the bit of code like this:
find -executable -type f | xargs mv $dir/* /tmp/     the error stays the same